# How to divide a LINQ query in small group to avoid Timeout expired exception?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have LINQ query as following

```
HashSet<Guid> temp1 ; // Getting this value through another method

var Ids = temp1.Except((from temp2 in prodContext.Documents 
                        where temp1.Contains(temp2.id) 
                        select temp2.id)).ToList();
```

Here, `temp1` has around 40k values. I'm getting timeout error sometimes, How can I divide this query using while or any other loop so that it won't give me timeout error. 
I tried to set Connect Timeout in connection string and for database context but nothing works.

Any suggestion please

Comment: @Christos Thanks for your quick response. I tried it but it's giving me same the error. "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."

Comment: @Christos : Not able to add comment under your answer so replied here

Comment: thanks for coming back. I am trying think about another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those unusual operations that is likely to be a query that can more effectively be performed in memory by the application rather than by the database.  Instead of trying to send all of the id values you have in your set to the DB, have it find all of the items with those IDs, and then send them all back to you, it's very plausibly better to just get *all* of the document ids and filter them on the application side of things.

```
var documentIds = prodContext.Documents.Select(doc => doc.id);
var Ids = temp1.Except(documentIds).ToList();
```

Now, depending on how many documents you have, even that could theoretically time out.  If it would, then you'll need to paginate the fetching of all of the document IDs.  You can use the following method to paginate any query to avoid fetching the entire result set all at once:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Paginate<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> query,
    int pageSize)
{
    int page = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        var nextPage = query.Skip(page * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .ToList();
        if (nextPage.Any())
            yield return nextPage;
        else
            yield break;
        page++;
    }
}
```

This allows you to write:

```
var documentIds = prodContext.Documents.Select(doc => doc.id)
    //play around with different batch sizes to see what works best
    .Paginate(someBatchSize)
    .SelectMany(x => x);
temp1.ExceptWith(documentIds);
```

Comment: where does page get incremented? Won't this only ever return the first "pagesize" of elements?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it where it combines both pagination and caching.

This way it only caches the one page size at a time to prevent memory overloading and prevent the time out. I hope this works.

```
int pageSize = 1000;

HashSet<Guid> temp1;

List<Guid> idsFromTable = new List<Guid>();

var Ids = temp1.ToList();
for(int i = 0; true; i++)
{
    //Cache the table locally to prevent logic running while selecting on page size
    idsFromTable.AddRange(prodContext.Documents.Skip(pageSize * i).Take(pageSize).Select(x=> x.id));

    if(idsFromTable.Any())
    {
        //Then use the cached list instead of the datacontext
        Ids = Ids.Except(idsFromTable).ToList();
        idsFromTable.Clear(); 
    }
    else
        break;
}
```

Comment: 1) If you're gonig to pull all of the data from the database, at least select out the ID before materializing the query, you need no other columns. 2) If you're going to take the time to fetch all of the IDs from the database there's no need for the `where`; it's only purpose is to avoid fetching them and bringing them into memory.  Having items in the `Except` that don't' exist in the first set will just do nothing, there's no need to take time to actively remove them first. 3) If fetching all of the items in the table would normally time out all hope is not lost, you can still paginate.

Comment: I improved my linq queries, however, it may improve performance just to cache the list from the start instead of dynamically loading data in the linq query.

Comment: @Taugenichts : I tried it and getting "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown." error.. Anyways thanks for your suggestion

Comment: So unfortunately, you do not have the memory to spare. Hopefully the answer below, with pagination works better since it won't all be cached at once. Let me know if you still don't have a solution.

Comment: Try this otherwise. I think this will do it. Also thanks for the pagination idea servy.

Comment: After your recent edits this is not just a slightly worse version of my answer.

Comment: Except you will cache it each time it runs, and will return the entire thing in memory and could potentially lead to the memory overflow. Mine at the very least clears the list each time it iterates to avoid that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to Servy's answer you might want to try paginating the queries as opposed to just pulling them all in. The efficiency of this depends on the DB you are using, I certainly got some mileage out of it on Informix. In this case the logic would look like this

```
HashSet<Guid> ids... //Got from another method
List<Guid> validIds = new List<Guid>();

const Int32 BUFFERSIZE = 1000;
var validationBuffer = new List<Guid>(BUFFERSIZE);

foreach(var g in ids)
{
    validationBuffer.Add(g)
    if(validationBuffer.Count == BUFFERSIZE)
    {
         validIds.AddRange(
             prodContext.Documents
                 .Select(t => t.id)
                 .Where(g => validationBuffer.Contains(g)));
         validationBuffer.Clear();
    }
}

//Do last query
validIds.AddRange(
    prodContext.Documents
        .Select(t => t.id)
        .Where(g => validationBuffer.Contains(g)));

var missingIds = ids.Except(validIds);
```

Comment: The OP has a *lot* of documents.  Querying that table N times where N is the number of groups that you have is going to be *very* expensive, particularly given that the actual operation that you're performing on all of those items is not a particularly efficient operation.  Each of the individual queries could very plausibly time out, and if they didn't, the whole operation is almost certainly going to take much, much longer than it needs to.

Comment: @Servy My experience with similar problems is that it can be the opposite, the main problem is that both solutions are sub-optimal, one has to try both out on typical id sets and choose which one is faster /  doesn't time out

Comment: @Servy Also consider given a pagination of size N either you are hitting the database with a simple query for (Document Count) / N queries or hitting it with a more complex query (ID Count) / N times, so essentially its an optimisation problem between document population, network speed, query speed, local id population and pagination size